# El Valor no puede ser NULO al insertar una imagen

Tags: c#, mysql, imagen, insert

cuando intento insertar una imagen a la base de datos MySQL todo funciona normal, pero al ejecutar una función  que haga que el tamaño de mi imagen sea mas pequeño e intentar insertarla, me muestra un error que dice [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el código para seleccionar la imagen:

```
private void pbImagen_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        try {

            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Filter = "choose Image(*.JPG;*.PNG)|*.jpg;*.png";

                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                convertir conv = new convertir()

                    pbImagen.Image = conv.RedimensionarImage(Bitmap.FromFile(ofd.FileName));
                    pbImagen.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;
                    pbImagen.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            }


          }
           catch {
                   MessageBox.Show("No Ingresaste Ninguna Imagen");     
                 }



    }
```

luego tenemos el código que reduce el tamaño de la imagen:

```
                public Bitmap RedimensionarImage(Image imgO)
        {
            var redimencion = new Bitmap(100, 100);
            Graphics.FromImage(redimencion).DrawImage(imgO, 0, 0, 100, 100);
            Bitmap ImagenFinal = new Bitmap(redimencion);

            return ImagenFinal;
        }
```

ya luego intento insertarlo a la base de datos pero me dice que es nulo el valor.
si esto lo intento sin reducir la imagen si funciona. 
alguien que me ayude por favor

Comment: antes de ingresarla a BD estas verificando el nuevo tamaño de la imagen ?

Comment: Hola, si revisas el mensaje de error, la excepción se produce en convertir.ImageToByteArray(). Pon un punto de parada en ese método y verifica los datos recibidos.

Comment: te falta el  punto y coma `;`  en la linea  `convertir conv = new convertir()`. Por lo demás parece que funciona correctamente.

Comment: Por otra parte veo que el resultado final lo estas estirando con `pbImagen.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;` no se si eso te esta induciendo a error. Un saludo y cualquier duda pregunta.

Comment: ya cuadre lo del " ; " y tambien lo de el  " pnImagen.sizemode " pero nada mi amigo, yo se que el error esta cuando vuelvo pequeña la imagen pero no se que pueda ser

Comment: Hola. Has verificado lo indicado en mi comentario? La verdad es que el mensaje de la excepción es muy explicativo de donde se está produciendo

Answer (score 0):

Amigo intentalo asi, al parecer tu metodo encargado de convertir a byte[] esta reventando:

```
       try
        {

            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Filter = "choose Image(*.JPG;*.PNG)|*.jpg;*.png";

            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(100, 100);
                //Image Image = RedimensionarImage(Bitmap.FromFile(ofd.FileName));
                newBitmap = RedimensionarImage(Bitmap.FromFile(ofd.FileName));
                MemoryStream NewMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                newBitmap.Save(NewMemoryStream, ImageFormat.Png);
                byte[] ReturnedThumbnail;
                ReturnedThumbnail = NewMemoryStream.ToArray();//en este punto ya te quedo el arreglo
                //pbImagen.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;
                //pbImagen.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            }


        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Ingresaste Ninguna Imagen");
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap RedimensionarImage(Image image)
    {
        Bitmap resizedImage = new Bitmap(100, 100);
        using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(resizedImage))
        {
            gfx.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100),
                new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }
        return resizedImage;
    }
}
```

Le ajuste algunas cosas al codigo para poder correrlo en mi maquina. Bueno se me fueron unos corchetes de mas pero lo vas ajustando, esto lo hice en base a este post:

[Resize image c#](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e2d8bd99-1af4-404a-a6bd-5fae9f540c2d/how-to-resize-an-image-in-byte-?forum=csharpgeneral)

Espero te sirva!

Comment: muchas gracias amigo, el código que me paso si me funciono, realmente quedo muy agradecido